# Mapear imagem e salvar array no banco

Tags: javascript, banco-de-dados

Eu tenho uma imagem da arcada dentária humana. Quero exibir ela e ao ser clicado em determinado dente, o valor fosse preenchendo em um campo input text.

Exemplo:

```
[13,12,11]
```

A imagem que vou usar é essa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A idéia é ao clicar no dente 11, 12 e 13 seus valores fossem preenchidosno campo do formulário para ser inserido no banco.

Acredito que isso é com javascript, mas estou perdida nisso. Poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: Bem vinda ao sopt. O que você já tentou fazer? Seria interessante postar um [mcve]. Assim fica mais fácil te orientar.

Comment: Essa imagem será sempre a mesma ou vais ter imagens diferentes para cada paciente?

Comment: @DiegoF não tenho idéia de como começar.

Comment: @Sergio vai ser a mesma imagem sim.

Comment: Sugiro usares algo mais prático. Um SVG seria melhor. Algo assim: https://jsfiddle.net/jkwj423z/ (com um bocado de trabalho pode ficar bem bom).

Comment: @Sergio a ideia é eu clicar em um determinado dente, exemplo: 10 e outro dente, 31 ... ao clicar nesses dois dentes, os valores 10 e 31 fossem para um campo input text de meu formulário.

Comment: Bom, já consegui mapear a imagem usando as tags abaixo: `<img src="_Imagens/arcada.png" width="500" border="0" usemap="#Map" class="bordaimg" />
                               
    <map name="Map" id="Map">
                  
                  <area shape="rect" coords="217,8,247,101"   href="javascript:AQUI_O_JS('11','dentes_id');" title="Dente 11" /></map>`

Comment: Agora estou quebrando a cabeça para fazer um JS que pegue o valor "11" e jogue no campo inpu text com o ID "dentes_id".

Answer (score 1):

Na wikipedia [há um SVG](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Human_dental_arches.svg) que pode ser [adaptado](https://jsfiddle.net/jkwj423z/6/) para ter numeros. Fiz essa adaptação e com um loop podes juntar auscultadores de eventos e um input que faz o que queres. O JavaScript poderia ser assim:

```
var paths = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('path.selectable'));
var text = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('text'));
var input = document.querySelector('input');
var selecionados = [];

for (var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
    paths[i].addEventListener('click', handler(text[i].innerHTML));
}

function handler(nr) {
    return function() {
        var selected = this.classList.toggle('selected');
        if (selected) selecionados.push(nr);
        else selecionados = selecionados.filter(function(_nr){ return _nr != nr; });
        input.value = selecionados.join(', ');
    }
}
```

O que isso faz é selecionar/de-selecionar dentes, e juntar o numero do dente selecionado no input.

### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4o0q7sc8/